# How can remove extra header space form UIViewController

Tags: ios, autolayout

How can remove extra header space between top navigation bar and tableview.

[image]

1. I have unchecked adjust scroll view insets but still now showing extra space.

Comment: can you please provide some screen shots of the extra space you want to be removed

Comment: Are you using UITableViewController?

Comment: NO.


i have UIViewController.

Comment: but i have customisation navigation bar using 
...........
let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height )

Comment: edge insets not found in tableview.

Comment: check for  self.tableView.contentInset if you have some

Comment: Sounds like auto layout problem

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it looks like an auto layout issue.

In the size inspector from the interface builder, can you please check and show us how it looks like? You can play with the final rendering of each of your elements.

Make also sure you don't have set specific constraints between elements.

This link provides useful informations to get started.

[Auto Layout](https://www.appcoda.com/learnswift/auto-layout-intro.html)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I see tutorial but not understand how to solve my issue